# Copy data between different domains

Tags: powershell, cross-domain, copy-paste

I want to use a powershell command which I want to execute from DomainA with user DomainA\X to go to domainB (no trust on domain but ports are open between domains).

On domainB I have user DomainB\Z, with that user I would like to get from servername `abcd01` (in domainB) a file from `D:\Test\Test.csv` and copy that back to DomainA servername `xyz01` to `D:\Test` folder location where user DomainA\X is having to appropriate rights.

Answer (score 0):

On the box in `DomainA`, establish a remote session on the box in `DomainB` with `New-PSSession`, then use `Copy-Item -FromSession` to copy the file:

```
# Create remote credentials
$remoteCredentials = Get-Credential DomainB\Z

# Create remote session
$remoteSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName abcd01.domainB.tld -Credential $remoteCredentials

# Copy file
Copy-Item -Path D:\Test\Test.csv -Destination D:\Test\ -FromSession $remoteSession
```

Suggested reading for getting more familiar with PowerShell Remoting: see the [`about_Remote`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote?view=powershell-5.1) and related help files

Comment: Thanks Mathias I got it working with a new ps-drive